# AWS / Quicksight / AWS4Signer / Signature Mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Iam trying to access ***datasets*** on quicksight using **AWS4Signer**, and i get the below response.

***"message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."***

I ensured, all the input parameters(region,servicename, etc..) Iam providing are correct.
Same SecretAccessKey is working correctly, when used with S3.

my ***DefaultRequest*** field that i supply to *aws4Signer.sign()* looks as below.

GET https://quicksight.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/accounts/19XXXXXXXX20/data-sets?max-results=10 / Parameters: ({"max-results":["10"]}Headers: (x-amz-content-sha256: required, )

Same thing works when i issue a CLI command as below.

> aws quicksight list-data-sets --aws-account-id 19XXXXXXXX20

Please let me know what could be missing here.
are there any quicksight specific headers that should be provided?